# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group with Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, native

i am having issue with generating build for IOS in xcode version 11.2.1

first was facing issue firebase.h not found , post that installed cocopods and installed firebase again , now that error has gone and above error has started to come.

[image]